# Java Apache HttpClient, Forward Proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache http client 4.5.14.
How can I make forward proxy ? I am using HttpClientBuilder and I can use setProxy() or setRoutePlanner() to set proxy.

Then how I can set proxy to be forward proxy ? Or maybe I don't need to do anything and it will detect if proxy is forward/reverse and it will work without any more code ?

@Edit more information

I have access to some api via forward proxy and I want apache http client to use this proxy. Unfortunately my code did not work correctly with this proxy and my guess was that I did not configurate something in my code, but I was unable to find information how to configurate forward proxy in apache http client. I am looking for some examle/information how can I use forward proxy in apache http client.

Comment: I don't get the exact need you have: do you want to implement a forwarding proxy by the use of apache httpclient, or just make the library use an existing proxy server in the network?
Also please note that a reverse proxy doesn't have to be configured to be used by a client that is accessing it, it should work transparently to the clients.

Comment: @cyberbrain I have access to some api via forward proxy and I want apache http client to use this proxy. Unfortunately my code did not work correctly with this proxy and my guess was that I did not configurate something in my code, but I was unable to find information how to configurate forward proxy in apache http client. I am looking for some examle/information how can I use forward proxy in apache http client.

Comment: please share some of the code you tried. This is the best way to get answers in SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apache httpclient project has a nice [example](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java) about how to use proxy on their pages. It's contained in the sources of the project as *ClientExecuteProxy.java*.

In short: you define two `HttpHost` objects, one for the actual target and one for the proxy. Then you set the proxy `HttpHost` in a custom `RequestConfig` with `setProxy(proxyHost)`.

```java
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("httpbin.org", 443, "https");
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setProxy(proxy)
        .build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/");
request.setConfig(config);
```